# how to get difference between two date

Tags: php

hey i want to get difference between two dates like

```
date1= 2014-03-3 
date2= 2014-03-4
```

when i sub this two date like **date2-date1** then it should give us **2**

ie. i just want to add new day after 12 am at night..how is it possible using php function?

I tried some code like

```
<?php $date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12"); 
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2); ?>
```

but it does not work

please help

Comment: Looks like it works: https://eval.in/108056

Comment: try to use the datetime object instead of date only ... check the following link http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2014-03-3');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-03-4');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$dayCount = $interval->format('%a');
echo $dayCount;
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/108057)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested just in numeric value you can do:

```php
$diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```
   $date1 = new DateTime("2013-03-15");
   $date2 = new DateTime("2013-12-12");
   $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
   echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
```

Comment: my question is when a day cover 12 at night then it adds 1 day with it

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it helps you

```
$datetime1 = strtotime('2014-03-3');
$datetime2 = strtotime('2014-03-4');
$timeDiff = $datetime2-$datetime1;
$dayCount=floor($timeDiff/(60*60*24)); //calculate day count.
echo $dayCount;
```

it will give you count 1, and if you provide the date with time then also it will work.